# HTTP Error 204, while trying to delete user from AppStore connect Test Flight, using RestAPI

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, app-store-connect-api

When I try to delete an existing user from TestFlight, I receive http error 204 (no content), what does this mean? I am sure my-user-id is existing in TestFlight, I got it via API.

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/betaTesters/{my-user-id}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer my-token'
```

Comment: an HTTP status code 204 is generally a success indicator for DELETE operations. If you want to verify that the user has been deleted, make an API request to retrieve the list of users or specifically query for the user to ensure their absence in the list.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is user is not deleted!

Comment: i flag to display the response headers, ( including the status code.) E.g.  curl -i --location --request DELETE 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/betaTesters/{my-user-id}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer my-token'. Is ther any more info